# Model Relationship Failing, Can't Get Data in Template

Tags: python, django

I have model Profile and another model called 'Nation', and this model will take Profile and User as ForeignKeys.

It's like this,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=M_CHOICES)

class Nation(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='natuser')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='nat_hr')
    ref_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=pm_tag)
```

The logic here is to check for the type of user and show fields 'values' related to the user model. For this, we believe the User belongs to the Nation model, so to get his ref number,

In Views, I did

```
@login_required
def profile_detail(request, username):
    user= get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    try:
        the_detail= user.profile
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return None
```

in Template, after checking that the user type belongs to the Nation model, I  wrote the below code to get the user ref_number but it's failing.

```
{{the_detail.nat_hr.ref_number}}

{{the_detail.user.profile.nat_hr.ref_number}}
```

What am I missing when it comes to using related_name to get data that belongs to a model via template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, ONE `Profile` can have MANY `Nation`s. Thus you should use a for loop to print each one of them like this:

```
{% for nation in the_detail.nat_hr.all %}
    {{nation.ref_number}}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Error:  '()' from 'the_detail.nat_hr.all()'.

Comment: @YoYo sorry, it should just be `.all`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Profile` can have many `Nation` objects, because `ForeignKey` realise a many-to-one relationship ([ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)). You can get set of `Nations` for current `Profile`.

Comment: Can you please explain further?

Comment: ForeignKey realise many-to-one relationship, that mean your 'Profile' can have many 'Nation'. In the same time 'Nation' can have only one 'Profile'. That's why you need to use loop or clarify what 'Profile' objects you need you can use query filter for this).